# Multidimensional Array Javascript with nested loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

For example i have a array like that

```
var myArray = [
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9,10],
[[11,12],[13,14,15]]];

    for (var i = 0;i < myArray.length;i++){
    for(var j = 0 ;j< myArray[i].length;j++){
        for(var k = 0;k< myArray[i][j].length;k++){
            console.log(myArray[i],[j][k]);

        }
    }
        
      
}
```

But output is only 11,12,13,14,15.
And i wanna print all the values
Could some one help to fix
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep flat multidimensional array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218858/deep-flat-multidimensional-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Write a function (`x`) that takes an array and iterates over the elements of that array. In the function test every element and if its an array call `x` with that array....

Comment: You have different levels of nesting in your array. `[1,2,3]` is in the "second level" whereas `[11,12]` and `[13,14,15]` are in the "third level".  So for instance `myArray[i][j].length` will be `undefined` for `i == 0`

Comment: That would be the perfect moment to use a recursive function, recalling itself each time one entry is an Array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use e.g. Array.prototype.flat(), .flat(2) flattens to the level of 2 arrays deep.

```js
var myArray = [
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9,10],
[[11,12],[13,14,15]]];

console.log(myArray.flat(2));
```

Comment: Why that _"magic number"_ `2`?

Comment: The depth level specifying how deep a nested array structure should be flattened. Defaults to 1.

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question ;)

Comment: you can write Infinity if you're not sure how many levels you have. was not specified in the question though

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive function
first pass it the whole array then loop it and check if the element you are accessing is array or digit
if its array call the same function again and only pass it this element
otherwise if its digit just print it

This works even when you dont know how many nested arrays you have otherwise use MWO answer

```js
var myArray = [
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9,10],
[[11,12],[13,14,15]]];

function printArray(arr){
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(Array.isArray(arr[i])){
      printArray(arr[i]);
    }else{
      console.log(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}

printArray(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This fucntion works for any depth of multi dimensional array. Using **Recursion**

```
var myArray = [1,2,33,44, [1,2,3], [[11,12],[13,14,15]]];

var myArray1 = [1,2,33,44, [[11,12],[13,14,15]]];


var deepFlattenArray = function (array){
    var result = []; 
    
    array.forEach(function (element) {
      if (Array.isArray(element)) {
          result = result.concat(deepFlattenArray(element)); 
      } else {
          result.push(element);
      }
    });
    
    return result;
};

console.log(deepFlattenArray(myArray));
 // output = [ 1,  2, 33, 44,  1, 2,  3, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

console.log(deepFlattenArray(myArray1));
// output = [1,  2, 33, 44, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]
```